# Angular Error: [$compile:tplrt] when template has only one root element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**UPDATE: This was a gulp issue, restarting gulp solved the problem.**

I am using Angular and trying to create a custom directive navbar.  But I am getting the following error:

```
Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'navbar' must have exactly one root element.
```

My template file only has one route element and the file path is correct, I can't figure out what else could be wrong?  Thanks

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="bemoApp">
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bemo</title>
    <!-- inject:js -->
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <!-- endinject -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <navbar></navbar>
    <section ui-view></section>
  </body>
</html>
```

**js/views/directives/navbar.html**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="register">Register</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="login">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**js/directives/navbar.js**

```
angular
  .module('bemoApp')
  .directive('navbar', navbar);

function navbar() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'js/views/directives/navbar.html',
    replace: true
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
function navbar() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'js/views/directives/navbar.html',
    replace: false
  };
}
```

there are some issues with that replace, so that may resolve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that stops the site loading at all.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've solved the problem now.  Turns out it was an issue with gulp and it just needed a restart.